# ¿Funcionan las notificaciones push silenciosas si el usuario tiene desactivadas las notificaciones?

Tags: android

Estoy aprendiendo las notificaciones push en Android y me ha surgido una duda a la hora de implementar la lógica de negocio.

He buscado y dicen que no es posible y lo recalcan en la [Google I/O 2012](https://youtu.be/Yc8YrVc47TI?t=48m4s), pero 'recientemente' ha salido en la [Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/w45y_w4skKs?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC&t=192) la opción de comprobarlo, pero eso no me responde a mi pregunta

> ¿Es posible recibir notificaciones push silenciosas cuando el usuario tiene las notificaciones desactivadas?

Comment: te refieres a una notificaciones sin sonido?

Comment: No, a las notificaciones que no ve el usuario, como servicio, para realizar peticiones al servidor y actualizar datos.